# How do I get a Django Server Error 500 report

Tags: django

I recently ran my tests on django for my project, one of them turned out as a server error 500. Thi confused me as I thought everything was passing. I currently have DEBUG=True. When I checked the documentation it said to set debug to true and add some admins to email for the full output. Is there an easier way to get the output or should I work on setting that up.

For more info my project is still being developed. I dont really want to post my test code as I really need more debugging experience but if you people ask I will!
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors are mailed throught Django logging framework. You must configure logging apropiatly to use other Handler than Email (email is by default for errors on django). Change it to Console or File Handler instead....

Here is the source doc:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/

Comment: Thanks I got it! I used the first example listed near word for word and i can read the output in the .log file i created.